# Add variable in php file with inside array using fwrite()?

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fwrite

I have problems to add variable in php file with inside array using `fwrite`.

My **php** file has an array and is like this:

```
<?php 
  $array48= array (
   0 => 
   array (
     0 => '2019-04-24-1248326-1313',
     1 => 1556110847000,
     2 => 30.6647,
     3 => 71.387200000000007,
     4 => 3.999999999999999,
     5 => 51,
     6 => 'O',
     7 => 13,
     8 => 0,
   )
 )
```

I want to add variable at first of file:

```
$fp_due_min_fa = fopen('../file.php', 'r+');
fwrite($fp_due_min_fa, '<?php ' . "\n" . '$id = ' . $id_terr . ';' . "\n");
fclose($fp_due_min_fa);
```

but after this code the php file is like this:

```
<?php 
  $id = 123456;
  556110847000,
     2 => 30.6647,
     3 => 71.387200000000007,
     4 => 3.999999999999999,
     5 => 51,
     6 => 'O',
     7 => 13,
     8 => 0,
   )
 )
```

The array is break...

**I would to have this output:**

```
<?php 
  $id = 123456;
  $array48= array (
   0 => 
   array (
     0 => '2019-04-24-1248326-1313',
     1 => 1556110847000,
     2 => 30.6647,
     3 => 71.387200000000007,
     4 => 3.999999999999999,
     5 => 51,
     6 => 'O',
     7 => 13,
     8 => 0,
   )
 )
```

Why I have this mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall design looks bad, but in general just read, concatenate and write to pre-pend to the beginning.  So as not to have to strip out the opening PHP tag, just open and close the tags:

```
$output = "<?php \$id = $id_terr; ?>\n";
$file   = file_get_contents('../file.php');
file_put_contents('../file.php', $output.$file);
```

Or to append (assuming there is no closing PHP tag as shown), simply:

```
file_put_contents('../file.php', "\n\$id = $id_terr;\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to append the data (  `file_put_contents()` with `FILE_APPEND`)

Comment: is there a possibility to append at first and not to the end of file ?

Comment: That's called pre-pend and that's the first example I showed.